# How to make for loops in Java increase by increments other than 1

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

If you have a for loop like this:

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j++){}
```

It works fine. But when you have a for loop like this:

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j+3){}
```

it doesn't work. Could someone please explain this to me?

Comment: +1 for trying something out yourself first before asking here.

Comment: The side-effect of `j++` is? The side-effect of `j+3` is?

Answer (score 137):

That’s because `j+3` doesn’t change the value of `j`. You need to replace that with `j = j + 3` or `j += 3` so that the value of `j` is increased by 3:

```
for (j = 0; j <= 90; j += 3) { }
```

Comment: Alternately he could `int j=0; for(;j<=90;){... j+=3;}` but that's nonobvious `;)`

Comment: @drachenstern In other words, a while loop.

Comment: @dkarp ~ Indeed, but seeing as how most people don't think about that syntax, thought I would point it out. Especially since the OP is obviously learning Java and programming at a young age (check the profee and the linked blog). I wish I had had SO at that age.

Answer (score 47):

Since nobody else has actually tackled `Could someone please explain this to me?` I believe I will:

`j++` is shorthand, it's not an actual operation (ok it really IS, but bear with me for the explanation)

`j++` is really equal to the operation `j = j + 1;` except it's not a macro or something that does inline replacement. There are a lot of discussions on here about the operations of `i+++++i` and what that means (because it could be intepreted as `i++ + ++i` OR `(i++)++ + i`

Which brings us to: `i++` versus `++i`. They are called the `post-increment` and `pre-increment` operators. Can you guess why they are so named? The important part is how they're used in assignments. For instance, you could do: `j=i++;` or `j=++i;` We shall now do an example experiment:

```
// declare them all with the same value, for clarity and debug flow purposes ;)
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

// yes we could have already set the value to 5 before, but I chose not to.
i = 5;

j = i++;
k = ++i;

print(i, j, k); 
//pretend this command prints them out nicely 
//to the console screen or something, it's an example
```

What are the values of i, j, and k?

I'll give you the answers and let you work it out ;)

`i = 7, j = 5, k = 7;` That's the power of the pre and post increment operators, and the hazards of using them wrong. But here's the alternate way of writing that same order of operations:

```
// declare them all with the same value, for clarity and debug flow purposes ;)
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int k = 0;

// yes we could have already set the value to 5 before, but I chose not to.
i = 5;

j = i;
i = i + 1; //post-increment

i = i + 1; //pre-increment
k = i;

print(i, j, k); 
//pretend this command prints them out nicely 
//to the console screen or something, it's an example
```

Ok, now that I've shown you how the `++` operator works, let's examine why it doesn't work for `j+3` ... Remember how I called it a "shorthand" earlier? That's just it, see the second example, because that's *effectively* what the compiler does before using the command (it's more complicated than that, but that's not for first explanations). So you'll see that the "expanded shorthand" has `i =` AND `i + 1` which is all that your request has.

This goes back to math. A function is defined where `f(x) = mx + b` or an equation `y = mx + b` so what do we call `mx + b` ... it's certainly not a function or equation. At most it is an expression. Which is all `j+3` is, an expression. An expression without assignment does us no good, but it does take up CPU time (assuming the compiler doesn't optimize it out).

---

I hope that clarifies things for you and gives you some room to ask new questions. Cheers!

Answer (score 10):

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j = j+3)
{

}
```

`j+3` will not assign the new value to j, add `j=j+3` will assign the new value to j and the loop will move up by 3.

`j++` is like saying `j = j+1`, so in that case your assigning the new value to j just like the one above.

Answer (score 9):

In your example, `j+=3` increments by 3.

(Not much else to say here, if it's syntax related I'd suggest Googling first, but I'm new here so I could be wrong.)

Comment: You're right, but the original question has `j+3` which *doesn't* actually increment `j`. The OP should use `j += 3`.

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j+3)
```

to

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j=j+3)
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be like this

```
for(int j = 0; j<=90; j += 3)
```

but watch out for

```
for(int j = 0; j<=90; j =+ 3)
```

or

```
for(int j = 0; j<=90; j = j + 3)
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply try this

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i=i+2){//value increased by 2
//body
}
```

OR

```
for(int i=0; i<5; i+=2){//value increased by 2
//body
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also write code as

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
      //statements;
      i=i+2;//cause you want to increment i by 3 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (let i = 0; i <= value; i+=n) { // increments by n
/*code statement*/
}
```

this format works for me incrementing index by n

```
for (let i = 0; i <= value; i+=4) { // increments by 4
/*code statement*/
}
```

if n = 4 this it will increment by 4

Answer (score 1):

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j++){}
```

j++ means j=j+1, j value already 0 now we are adding 1 so now the sum value of j+1 became 1, finally we are overriding the j value(0) with the sum value(1)
     so here we are overriding the j value by j+1. So each iteration j value will be incremented by 1.

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j+3){}
```

Here j+3 means j value already 0 now we are adding 3 so now the sum value of j+3 became 3 but we are not overriding the existing j value. So that JVM asking the programmer, you are calculating the new value but where you are assigning that value to a variable(i.e j). That's why we are getting the compile-time error " invalid AssignmentOperator ".

If we want to increment j value by 3 then we can use any one of the following way.

```
 for (int j=0; j<=90; j+=3)  --> here each iteration j value will be incremented by 3.
 for (int j=0; j<=90; j=j+3) --> here each iteration j value will be incremented by 3.
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a syntax error. You just have to replace `j+3` by `j=j+3` or `j+=3`.

Answer (score 0):

The "increment" portion of a loop statement has to change the value of the index variable to have any effect. The longhand form of "++j" is "j = j + 1". So, as other answers have said, the correct form of your increment is "j = j + 3", which doesn't have as terse a shorthand as incrementing by one. "j + 3", as you know by now, doesn't actually change j; it's an expression whose evaluation has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a for loop like this:

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j++){}
```

In this loop you are using shorthand provided by java language which means a postfix operator(use-then-change) which is equivalent to j=j+1 , so the changed value is initialized and used for next operation.

```
for(j = 0; j<=90; j+3){}
```

In this loop you are just increment your value by 3 but not initializing it back to j variable, so the value of j remains changed.